# the value of the complex number $z=(i\sqrt{3}-1)^{3\over 4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the value of the complex number

(I want the value not the roots)

$z=(i\sqrt{3}-1)^{3\over 4}$

My answer:

$z^4=(i\sqrt{3}-1)^3$

$z^4=2(-1-i\sqrt{3})(-1+i\sqrt{3})$

$z^4=8$

$z$ = the fourth root of $8$

True ?

Comment: True. But which one? (Maybe nothing is to be added...)

Comment: You seem determined, here and in your previous question, to avoid the simple fact that, when $w$ is a complex number not positive real, $w^{1/4}$ is not a complex number but, depending on the convention, either nonexistent or a collection of complex numbers. Hence the question "Find the value of the complex number $w^{1/4}$" is absurd from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that $z$ is "a" fourth root of $8$, not "the" fourth root of $8$. There is no such thing as "the" fourth root of $8$. $z$ has four possible values, and it's up to you to specify which one is intended. In other words, you have to specify a branch of the logarithm in order to compute any of the possible values.

So if $\sqrt[4]{8}$ is the positive real number, then $z$ could be any of the four numbers in the set $$\{\sqrt[4]{8},-\sqrt[4]{8},i\sqrt[4]{8},-i\sqrt[4]{8}\}$$